# how to change the matrix point coordination in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, vector, matrix, point

I would like to know if it is possible to change the coordination of matrix Point2f in OpenCV.

if that isn't possible i would like to create a matrix from a vector of

> Point2f

and

> uchar

the vector holds the Point2f and the value of the point, the matrix should be an image which means it has more than 1 dimension

EDIT:

In other words I want to create a new Matrix with a new scale of Point2f for example the Matrix :

```
      1 2 3
  m=  4 5 6
      7 8 9
```

the m(0,0) correspond to the Point (1.10,0) and  m(0,1) => point(2.20,0) 
and m(0.2) => point(3.30,0) and m(1,0) => point(1.10,1.40) and m(1,1) => point(1.10,2.00)
m(1,2) => point(1.10,2.60)

thank you in advance :)

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by "coordination of matrix"?

Comment: the points of a matrix

Comment: `p1.x = some_value`, `p1.y = some_value`